# Ayuda con un ejercicio en java

Tags: java

Cree un programa que solicite dos valores enteros A, B por teclado y posteriormente muestre en
pantalla la suma de todos los números pares mayores que A y menores que B. Debe validarse que el
número B sea mayor que el número A, en caso contrario se deben volver a solicitar los números al
usuario.

En eclipse o en cualquier otro programa que use lenguaje java.

Esto es lo que he intentado hasta ahora:

```
public class error {

    int a;
    int b;

    public void valor1(){
       for(int i=0;i>a;i++){
           if(i>a){

           }    
       }

    }
}
```

Comment: Si es java, en eclipse y asi.

Comment: Coloca lo que has intentado hasta ahora, de esa manera podemos ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: public class error {
int a;
int b;

public void valor1(){
for(int i=0;i>a;i++){
if(i>a){
 
}
  
 }

}
}

Comment: Aqui tienes que hacer del uso de scanner(para poder ingresar datos) , y del system.out.println(para poder mostrar por pantalla)

Comment: Si eso ya lo tengo... Lo que quiero es el ciclo para sacar los numeros pares mayores y los numeros menores que B eso es lo que necesito.

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro Deberías de editar tu pregunta dejando claro lo que quieres solucionar en tu programa y lo que tienes resuelto. De esta manera será mucho más fácil ayudarte.

Comment: @DiegoAlejandro si ya conocias la manera pero no obtener los numeros pares, con 1 sola pregunta en Google encuentras miles de respuestas. Si hubieses sido mas claro con tu pregunta mucho mas rapido te hubieramos ayudado, tienes 4 respuestas con la cual elegir :D

Comment: Esta pregunta es de mal gusto. Aunque compartistes el código que tienes hasta ahora, la verdad es que no refleja ningun esfuerzo concreto de tu parte. Lo correcto es de hacer un esfuerzo sincero por cumplir con tu tarea antes de pedir ayuda. Y de ser necesario pedir ayuda, debería ser en cuanto a un obstaculo *específico*, no para pedir que otros hagan el trabajo completo por ti. Aunque, al fin y al cabo, el que sale perdiendo eres tu, porque no te ayuda en tu aprentizaje.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba así:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class RangePrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);

        int min = 0;
        int max = 0;

        while(min >= max)
        {
            System.out.println("Ingresa el primer numero");
            min=reader.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo numero");
            max=reader.nextInt();

            if(min >= max)
                System.out.println("El rango ingresado es incorrecto.");
        }

        int result = 0;

        for (int i=min + 1; i < max; i++)
        {
            if(i % 2 == 0)
                result += i;
        }

        System.out.println("Resultado: "+result);
   }
}
```

Comment: Hola @Jemonge. Por más que el código sea más que evidente, a veces conviene explicar muy brevemente qué es lo que se está proponiendo y por qué esto solucionaría la pregunta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes probar con algo así

El usuario ingresa los valores, se verifica que `numero` sea siempre mayor que `numero2`, si no, repetimos hasta que se cumpla esa condición.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int suma = 0;
    int numero = 0;
    int numero2 = 0;
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Ingresa el primer numero");
        numero = reader.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Ingresa el segundo numero");
        numero2 = reader.nextInt();

        if (numero > numero2)
            System.out.println("El primer numero debe ser menor al segundo");
    } while (numero > numero2);

    //Se suma 1, porque el enunciado dice números pares MAYORES A (numero2) y menores que B (numero)
    for (int i = numero + 1; i < numero2; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            System.out.println("numero par " + i);
            suma = suma + i;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(suma);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

podria ser algo asi:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese a:");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese b:");
        int b = sc.nextInt();
        while(a > b){//si a > b vuelvo a pedir los datos
            System.out.println("el valor de a debe ser menor que b");
            System.out.println("Ingrese a:");
            a = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Ingrese b:");
            b = sc.nextInt();
        }
        //hasta aqui todo bien entonces prosigo a sumar los pares entre a y b
        int suma = 0;
        for(int i = a + 1; i < b; i++){
            if(i % 2 == 0){
                suma = suma + i;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("La suma de los pares entre a y b es:");
        System.out.println(suma);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error no considerado :'(");
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar lo siguiente:

```
public class error {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int a;
    int b;
    Scanner leerTeclado = new Scanner(System.in);
    while(true){
        System.out.print("Introduce el valor A: ");
        a=leerTeclado.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Introduce el valor B: ");
        b=leerTeclado.nextInt();
        if(b>a)
            break;
    }
    int pos=a+1;
    while(true){
        if(pos<b){
            if(pos%2==0){
                System.out.println("Valor par mayor que A y menor que B: "+pos);
            }
            pos++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

}